# SmartGIT Stuck on "Exhausted Available Authentication Methods"

Tags: windows, ssh, git

A few days ago, a Git server (using Gitlab) I work on had some changes made and went down for a while.  I believe that they moved it to a different machine.  I access with SmartGit and use SSH keys for authentication.  I was getting a warning about the SSH fingerprint change, so I went in and cleared out my known hosts file.  However, I also started to get a "Exhausted Available Authentication Methods" error when I tried to pull.  I updated my SSH keys without any luck.  Using Git via Gitbash works just fine with the current SSH keys.  I tried to completely uninstall and reinstall SmartGit (including clearing out appdata folder), I don't think it uses Windows Registry, but I'm still getting the error.  I do know that the error is coming from SSH.  I know my SmartGit isn't the current version since my upgrade support ran out last year.

Git on the command line via GitBash does currently work with my current SSH key.  SmartGit still works except for interacting with the remote server so I'm switching tools all the time now to get stuff done.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the hunt for the solution for me as well.  This is related to the recent changes in OpenSSH where PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms no longer includes the ssh-rsa algorithm. Older ssh keys were often created with that encryption.  That includes the one I've been using for a number of years, and apparently SmartGit is not passing the correct parameters to force the SSH client to accept them.

Not sure yet how to solve it properly, but by tailing the logs of my Gitea server, at least I figured out why I could login via command line using my system SSH, but SmartGit was failing with the "Exhausted available authentication methods" error.

One thing I have found **does work** is to go to Edit->Preferences->Authentication and change the radio button to `Use system SSH client` and make sure your system client has a `C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\config` file that is configured like this:

```
Host your-ssh-domain.com
    HostName your-ssh-domain.com
    Port 22
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/your-ssh-key.priv.pem
```

When SmartGit uses the system SSH, it will pick up your SSH key and connect just fine.  I would much prefer use the internal one, but for now, this works.